# Pandas Multiple column comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of columns with Dataframes:
[List of Columns and Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Npi.png)

```
Df = ["correct_New", "miss_New", "wrong_New", "correct_Old","miss_Old","wrong_Old"]
ListNew = ["correct_New", "miss_New", "wrong_New"]
ListOld = ["correct_Old","miss_Old","wrong_Old"]

#Dropping equivalent
df_merge_files  = Df[ListNew] != Df[ListOld]

#Going to save only the differences. 
df_merge_files.to_csv("comparison_report.csv", sep=';', index=False)
```

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: Your sample code can't be right as `Df` is a list. Can we please have a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df_merge_files  = Df[ListNew].rename(columns=dict(zip(ListNew, ListOld))) != Df[ListOld]
```

The column names have to match, when you do this kind of comparison.

Alternatively you can convert them both to `numpy` and work from there:

```py
df_merge_files  = Df[ListNew].to_numpy() != Df[ListOld].to_numpy()
```